# What evidence is needed for a dependent sibling of a family member of an EU citizen?

Tags: family, eu-spouses

I'm an EU citizen (British) and my wife is Filipina. We live in Spain and my wife is here as a family member of an EU citizen with an Article 10 residence card.

Her sister is dependent on us and my understanding is that she should be able to join us here on that basis. However, I haven't been able to find any clear information about the proof that's required for her dependency. We do send her money regularly but not on any particular schedule or a specific amount. Basically we send money whenever she needs it. Would this likely be a problem? If we were to provide bank statements, would it be expected that the payments stick to a specific schedule and be the same amount each time?

In addition, are there any specifics on how long the regular payments should have been made for, or does it need to be a certain minimum amount? Right now we've been sending payments on and off for around the last six months, usually €100 or €200 at a time. Are there any rules specifying the amounts and frequency of money sent to a family member for them to be considered 'dependent'?

I would appreciate it if anybody has any experience following this process and can give me any more specific information as I've had trouble finding any online.

Comment: I suspect that they will be interested in the percentage of your sister-in-law's budget represented by your payments, and in the magnitude of her living expenses relative to the cost of living in her place of residence, more than in the payments' regularity, frequency or absolute value.  The language of the directive, though, implies that she should be dependent on you *in the same country as you* before you moved to Spain.  If she never lived with you, and you've been sending money, her not being able to move to Spain doesn't impede your ability to move to Spain or to stay there.

Answer (score 1):

Dependent more usually means elderly parents or young children who are cared for. If this sibling is an adult then once they arrive in Spain they could get a job and would no longer be dependent.

Comment: That is true, but the directive does not exclude siblings or siblings in law, and it does not mention the prospect of becoming independent as a disqualifying condition or otherwise.

Comment: @phoog looks like your comment should be an answer, with my answer after some editing becoming an illustrative comment. The intent of the directive being, I take it, to encompass relatives who are practically dependent rather than just financially dependent, such as disabled adult siblings.

Comment: I haven't answered because I know next to nothing about Spain's transposition or implementation of the directive, but if nobody else does by tomorrow I might add an answer.